# Web Service JSON request - accept both single value and array of values

Tags: arrays, json, rest

I am designing a web service accepting `POST` requests with JSON in the message body. I want the requestor to be able to specify multiple values for a parameter, but also single values.

So, for simple cases I support JSON like:

```
{
    "name" : "value"
}
```

And, in more complex cases, I also support JSON like:

```
{
    "name" : [
        "value one",
        "value two",
        "value three"
    ]
}
```

*My question is:* is this an abnormal interface for a Web Service? Am I overcomplicating things here?

The alternative would be, as I want to support arrays of values, to require arrays of values, even for the simple case:

```
{
    "name" : [
        "value"
    ]
}
```

I don't like this but want to get the community's input before making a decision.

**EDIT:**
I removed the word REST from the conversation as that factor isn't really important here.

Answer (score 0):

It is typical of a web service to accept an array of values for a `POST` request. However, the number of elements may be zero or many. Keeping it as an array of values, even if only one value is going in, is going to keep things simple and consistent.

If a user of the web service needs to submit a single element for creation or modification (upsert), then perhaps a `PUT` request would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer a single structure for both cases and then there will be only one processing logic to code and no need for special case to decide on.

Also this is not much of REST related. It is more of on trading off on the the processing or handling of the data v.s. whatever reasons that drive you to think of splitting the data into two forms in the first place.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

REST is about resources and their representations. So ask yourself:

> What resource does the JSON represent?

Can you answer this question?

From the JSON in your question I would say, the resource is *an object that has names*
. It is *not* an object that has *one* name.

So I recommend to use your second approach.

Comment: Very true, but, the part I'm struggling with is the values. Each name may have one or more values, so do I require the values to be in an array, even though one value is perfectly valid?